# Weird behavior when using the operator in with a subquery

Tags: mysql

I'm a student and I'm new to stackoverflow, so I'll say sorry in advance if there is something I missed.

Recently, I've encountered a weird error with a database, which is about car races and racers who won those
exact races. The following code was supposed to be used for finding out which
racers won a race that was held in Sweden:

```
select *
from drivers
where concat(Ime, ' ', Prezime) = any (select vozac from results  where Godina = 1996);
```

For whatever reason, this would return twice than the amount of data there is in the table drivers, which is 20.
But the following code, or the alternative worked as intended, returning the 2 rows that
represent the drivers/racers that won the race:

```
select *
from drivers
where concat(Ime, ' ', Prezime) = any (select concat(r.ime, " ",r.prezime) from test_results r where r.Godina = 1996);

/*Alternative way of doing this: */
select *
from drivers
where concat(Ime, ' ', Prezime) = any (select concat(vozac,"") from results  where Godina = 1996);
```

I fixed the problem already, as it is a very simple query, but my question is:
How does this work? Why doesn't the code work as intended? Why does vozac alone duplicate the amount of
rows in the view "drivers", but casting it as char or adding on it an empty string with concat works as
intended?

Here is the video of the query returning 40 results, as opposed to the "correct" ones returning 2: (sorry, I can't seem to find a video upload so I will have to do with a separate site.)
[The video](https://streamable.com/534juw)

Again, I'm sorry if I'm not making any sense, or if there's something more I need to mention, this is my first time on stackOverflow. Thanks in advance to anyone reading this?
The code for the database and the views in question:

```
CREATE DATABASE rally;
USE rally;

CREATE TABLE konstruktor (
    id_konstruktor INT,
    naziv VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    drzava VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    godina_uspostavljanje INT4 NOT NULL,
    godina_zavrsetka INT4,
    CONSTRAINT pk_konstruktor PRIMARY KEY (id_konstruktor)
);

insert into konstruktor values
(1, 'Lancia', 'Italija', 1970, 1992),
(2, 'Audi', 'Nemacka',  1980, 1987),
(3, 'Subaru', 'Japan', 1989, 2008),
(4, 'Toyota', 'Japan', 2017, null),
(5, 'Volskwagen', 'Nemacka', 1978, 2016),
(6, 'Citroen', 'Francuska', 2003, 2019),
(7, 'Hyundai', 'Juzna Korea', 1999, null),
(8, 'Ford', 'Amerika', 1997, null),
(9, 'Peugeot', 'Francuska', 1981, 2005),
(10, 'Mitsubishi','Japan', 1967, 2002),
(11, 'Fiat','Italija', 1973, 1981),
(12, 'Opel','Nemacka', 1982, 1990),
(13, 'Posche','Nemacka', 1965, 1984),
(14, 'Alpine-Renault','Francuska', 1976, 1995),
(15, 'Skoda', 'Ceska', 1999, 2013);


CREATE TABLE kategorija (
    id_kategorija INT,
    naziv VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    godina_uspostavljanje INT4 NOT NULL,
    godina_zavrsetka INT4 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_kat PRIMARY KEY (id_kategorija)
);

insert into kategorija values
(1, 'Grupa B', 1982, 1986),
(2, 'Grupa A', 1987, 1996),
(3, 'World Rally Cars', 1997, 2016),
(4, 'WRC present', 2017, 2021),
(5, 'Grupa 4', 1966, 1983)
;
CREATE TABLE kola (
    id_kola INT,
    proizvodjac INT NOT NULL,
    kategorija INT NOT NULL,
    naziv_modela VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    kubikaza INT NOT NULL,
    snaga INT NOT NULL,
    pogon VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    Ubrzanja DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_kola PRIMARY KEY (id_kola),
    CONSTRAINT fk_kola_konstruktor FOREIGN KEY (proizvodjac)
        REFERENCES konstruktor (id_konstruktor),
    CONSTRAINT fk_kola_kat FOREIGN KEY (kategorija)
        REFERENCES kategorija (id_kategorija)
);

insert into kola values
(1, 2, 1, 'Sport Quattro S1', 2110, 540, '4WD', 3.1),
(2, 8, 1, 'RS200 Evolution', 1803, 580, '4WD', 3.07),
(3, 3, 2, 'Impreza S3 WRC', 1994, 310, '4WD', 5.0),
(4, 10, 2, 'Lancer Evolution IV', 1997, 280,'4WD', 5.5),
(5, 8, 5, 'Escort RS1800', 1834, 113, 'RWD', 8.2),
(6, 11, 5, '131 Abarth', 1995, 140, 'RWD', 7.8),
(7, 9, 1, '205 T16', 1775, 460,'4WD', 4.5),
(8, 8, 3, 'Focus WRC MK1', 1990, 300, '4WD', 4.2),
(9, 6, 3, 'C4 WRC',  2000, 315, '4WD', 4.0),
(10, 1, 5, 'Stratos', 2418, 265, 'RWD', 4.1),
(11, 1, 1, '037', 1995, 300, 'RWD', 4.3),
(12, 12, 1, 'Ascona 400', 1300, 275, 'RWD', 4.5),
(13, 4, 2, 'Celica GT-Four WRC', 3397, 295,'4WD', 4.3),
(14, 13, 1, '959 Rally', 3164, 444, '4WD', 3.6),
(15, 14, 5, 'A110', 1289, 70, 'FWD', 13.0),
(16, 6, 3, 'Xsara T4 WRC', 1998, 310, '4WD', 3.7),
(17, 7, 4, 'i20 N Rally1', 1600, 514, '4WD', 6.2),
(18, 8, 4, 'Puma Hybrid Rally1', 1600, 493, '4WD',  3.2),
(19, 4, 4, 'GR YARIS Rally1', 1600,  510, '4WD', 5.5),
(20, 15, 3, 'Octavia WRC', 1984, 300, 'FWD', 6.0),
(21, 1, 1, 'Delta S4', 1759, 450, '4WD', 6.0),
(22, 5, 3, 'Polo R WRC', 1605, 217, 'FWD', 6.4)
;


CREATE TABLE vozac (
    id_vozaca INT,
    ime VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    prezime VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    nacionalnost VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    datum_rodjenje DATE NOT NULL,
    datum_smrti DATE,
    ekipa INT NOT NULL,
    kola INT NOT NULL,
    broj_pobeda INT NOT NULL,
    broj_sampionata INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_vozac PRIMARY KEY (id_vozaca),
    CONSTRAINT fk_vozac_ekipa FOREIGN KEY (ekipa)
        REFERENCES konstruktor (id_konstruktor),
    CONSTRAINT fk_vozac_kola FOREIGN KEY (kola)
        REFERENCES kola (id_kola)
);
INSERT INTO vozac VALUES
(1, 'Walter', 'Rohrl', 'DEU', '1947-3-7', NULL, 1, 11, 14, 2),
(2, 'Timo', 'Salonen', 'FIN', '1951-10-8', NULL, 9, 7, 11, 1),
(3, 'Stig', 'Blomqvist', 'SWE','1946-7-29', NULL, 2, 1, 11, 1),
(4, 'Juha', 'Kankkunen', 'FIN', '1959-4-2', NULL, 9, 7, 23, 4),
(5, 'Hannu', 'Mikkola', 'FIN', '1942-5-24', '2021-2-25', 2, 1, 18, 1),
(6, 'Michele','Mouton','FRA','1951-6-23',NULL, 2, 1, 4, 0),
(7, 'Henri','Toivonen', 'FIN', '1956-8-25', '1986-3-2', 1, 21, 3, 0),
(8, 'Colin', 'McRae', 'GBR', '1968-8-5', '2007-9-15', 3, 3, 25, 1),
(9, 'Kalle', 'Rovanpera', 'FIN', '2000-10-1', NULL, 4, 19, 8, 1),
(10, 'Carlos', 'Sainz', 'ESP', '1962-4-12', NULL, 4, 13, 26, 2),
(11, 'Sebastien', 'Loeb', 'FRA','1974-2-26',NULL, 6, 9, 80, 9),
(12, 'Sebastien', 'Ogier', 'FRA', '1983-12-17',NULL, 5, 22, 55, 8),
(13, 'Sandro', 'Munari', 'ITA', '1940-3-27',NULL, 1, 10, 7, 1),
(14, 'Peter', 'Solberg', 'NOR', '1974-11-18',NULL, 3, 3, 10, 2),
(15, 'Richard', 'Burns', 'GBR', '1971-1-17',NULL, 3, 3, 10, 1),
(16, 'Didier', 'Auriol', 'FRA', '1958-8-18',NULL, 4, 13, 20, 1),
(17, 'Tommi', 'Makinen', 'FIN', '1964-6-26',NULL, 10, 4, 24, 1),
(18, 'Miki', 'Biasion', 'ITA', '1958-1-7', NULL, 1, 21, 17,2),
(19, 'Ott', 'Tanak', 'EST', '1987-10-15', NULL, 4, 19, 17, 1),
(20, 'Ari', 'Vatenen', 'FIN', '1952-4-27', NULL, 8, 2, 10, 1);

CREATE TABLE staza (
    id_staza INT,
    naziv VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    lokacija VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    duzina DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    teren ENUM('asfalt', 'sljunak', 'zemlja', 'sneg'),
    CONSTRAINT pk_staza PRIMARY KEY (id_staza)
);
INSERT INTO staza VALUES
(1, 'Rallye Monte-Carlo', 'Monaco', 257.64, 'asfalt'),
(2, 'Rally Sweden', 'Sweden', 264.81 , 'sneg'),
(3, 'Croatia Rally', 'Croatia', 291.84, 'asfalt'),
(4, 'Rally de Portugal', 'Portugal', 330.17, 'sljunak'),
(5, 'Rally Italia Sardegna','Italy', 307.91, 'sljunak'),
(6, 'Safari Rally', 'Kenya', 363.44, 'sljunak'),
(7, 'Rally Estonia', 'Estonia', 313.84, 'sljunak'),
(8, 'Jordan Rally', 'Jordan',359.26 ,'sljunak'),
(9, 'Rally Finland', 'Finland', 322.61 , 'sljunak'),
(10, 'Ypres Rally', 'Belgium', 281.58, 'asfalt'),
(11, 'Acropolis Rally', 'Greece', 303.30, 'sljunak'),
(12, 'Rally New Zealand', 'New Zealand', 279.80, 'sljunak'),
(13, 'Rally Catalunya', 'Spain', 293.77, 'asfalt'),
(14, 'Rally Japan', 'Japan', 283.27, 'asfalt'),
(15, 'Wales Rally', 'Great Britain', 348.32, 'sljunak'),
(16, 'Tour de Corse', 'France', 347.51, 'asfalt'),
(17, 'Rallye Sanremo', 'Italy', 220.03, 'asfalt'),
(18, 'Rally Argentina', 'Argentina', 238.62, 'sljunak'),
(19, 'Rally Australia', 'Australia', 355.39, 'sljunak'),
(20, 'Rallye Deutschland', 'Germany', 355.39, 'sljunak');



CREATE TABLE takmicenje (
    staza INT NOT NULL,
    vozac INT NOT NULL,
    pozicija ENUM('1', '2', '3'),
    godina INT4 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_takmicenje PRIMARY KEY (staza , vozac , godina),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tak_staza FOREIGN KEY (staza)
        REFERENCES staza (id_staza),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tak_vozac FOREIGN KEY (vozac)
        REFERENCES vozac (id_vozaca)
);

INSERT INTO takmicenje VALUES
(11, 1, '1', 1983),
(2, 8, '3', 1996),
(19, 10, '3', 1996),
(18, 10, '1', 2004),
(4, 11,'2', 2010),
(13, 11, '1', 2009),
(2, 5, '1', 1981),
(12, 5, '3', 1984),
(4, 1, '3', 1983),
(9, 19, '1', 2018),
(20, 19, '1', 2019),
(15, 6, '2', 1982),
(6, 6, '3', 1983),
(17, 6, '1', 1981),
(15,8,'1', 1995),
(12, 8, '1', 1995),
(19, 8, '2', 1995),
(13, 8, '2', 1995);

create view drivers as
select v.id_vozaca 'id', v.ime 'Ime', v.prezime 'Prezime', v.nacionalnost 'Nacionalnost', v.datum_rodjenje 'Datum Rodjenje', v.datum_smrti 'Datum Smrti',
e.naziv 'Ekipa', k.naziv_modela 'Model', kat.naziv 'Kategorija'
from vozac v inner join konstruktor e on v.ekipa = e.id_konstruktor
  inner join kola k on v.kola = k.id_kola
        inner join kategorija kat on kat.id_kategorija = k.kategorija;

create view results as
select s.naziv 'Naziv', s.lokacija 'Lokacija', tak.godina 'Godina', tak.pozicija 'Pozicija', concat(v.ime, " " ,v.prezime,"") "vozac"
from takmicenje tak inner join staza s on tak.staza = s.id_staza
   inner join vozac v on tak.vozac = v.id_vozaca;
                 
create view test_results as
select s.naziv 'Naziv', s.lokacija 'Lokacija', tak.godina 'Godina', v.ime, v.prezime, tak.pozicija 'Pozicija'
from takmicenje tak inner join staza s on tak.staza = s.id_staza
   inner join vozac v on tak.vozac = v.id_vozaca;
```

I tried replicating the same issue on other databases I had, but to no avail. I'm sorry for the lack of information.

Comment: Can you please run the query `SELECT @@version;` and tell us what it returns? If the query doesn't work, please try `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: The version it says is 8.0.30.

Comment: Any idea as to what is happening? I would like some help.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking. The three queries you show return identical results. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/-0h-fWeQ

Comment: Hmm I guess the problem is with my own Mysql Workbench including the building's Mysql Workbench being outdated?

Comment: I don't think the version of the client makes any difference to the query result. The query is executed by the MySQL Server, not the client. I suspect you just got mixed up with your tests.

Comment: No, I tested it for 2 hours, and now aswell and it is returning more rows than it should. 
I may be making a mistake regarding this, but I can show a video, I just need somewhere where I can post it.

Comment: Alright, I edited the comment and posted the link to the video. Also, I apologize if I sound rude.

Comment: Thank you for the effort of posting a video. I've done some more testing and I can reproduce the problem, but I have no explanation for it. I was able to work around it: `select *
from drivers
where concat(Ime, ' ', Prezime) = any (select vozac from results  where Godina = 1996) = true;` But I have no idea why that solution works.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry for wasting your time, I just wished to know why such a thing even happens in the first place, since this is a thing I haven't ever encountered before. Thank you for your time though!